# Moving search to top menu

Tags: xml, magento

I'm trying to move the search field from the header to the topmenu 'Megamenu' (extension), but I can't seem to find the right way to do this in the XML. I'm working with the Porto theme (from Smartwave). The topmenu.phtml is located in `root/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Megamenu/templates/topmenu.phtml`

I copied `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top.search"); ?>` from `header.phtml` to this `topmenu.phtml`, but it's now showing. (topSearch doesn't work either).

In default.xml (in Smartwave_Porto) the relevant part looks like this:

```
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
                <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
                </block>

            </referenceContainer>
            <move element="top.search" destination="porto_header"/>
```

In `Smartwave_Megamenu/layout/default.xml` I tried adding the following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
```

I'm not sure what to use instead of 'root', but I guess I'm doing something else wrong too.

edit:
[image]

Comment: can you provide image?

Comment: Added. Or you meant something else?

Comment: Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I did this in magento 1.9, by only CSS changes. you should post this question on http://magento.stackexchange.com/